# no raw_query method in my django object

Tags: python, django, mongodb

First, apologies for this question. You may find this very easy/simple, but I've been searching this for hours already. Anyways, I am trying to do a `raw_query` on my django project, which uses mongodb-engine `DictField`. However, my django object/model has no `raw_query` method.

```
MyModel.objects.raw_query({'foo':'bar'})
```

When I do the above code on my django-shell, I am receiving this error:

> AtttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'raw_query'

Should I be importing other modules here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly import and use the low-level `MongoDBManager` instead of the default manager if you want to use the raw query methods, as described in [the docs](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/lowerlevel.html):

```
from django_mongodb_engine.contrib import MongoDBManager

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = MongoDBManager()
```

Comment: thanks but doing this, I am getting this error: "'Manager' object is not callable"... Am I missing some imports here? Like import djangotoolbox?

Comment: question again Daniel... how do I use regex on raw_query? when I use "{'foo.bar': {$regex:'.*test.*'}}, django shell complains for an invalid syntax. I also tried '{'foo.bar': '.*test.*'} assuming that the regex will take effect. But the result is empty